# Is it possible to tell viewport Ambient Occlusion to ignore edge lines in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, interface, 3d-view, edit-mode, edges

How can I get rid of that weird shadows for edges in edit mode with viewport Ambient Occlusion (Properties Panel > Shading) enabled?

AO disabled

[image]

AO enabled

[image]

Comment: Has the object you are working on a subdivision surface modifier?

Comment: @Carlo Yes, It has a subdivision surface modifier, but I don't understand why do you ask?

Comment: I asked for having more info about of why "the lines" are generated only upon certain edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disable Faces Overlay

Because the way viewport's AO is currently built (2.77), everything is drawn in the 3D viewport is taken into account.

[image]

What you see is probably the projection of adjusted faces that comes from the unmodified mesh. Basically, as in edit mode you see **two version** of the same geometry (even with "Adjust cage ..." enabled, it's only projected upon the modified mesh), you get **AO from both meshes**.

[image]

If it is suitable for your workflow, one possible workaround could be to **disable the Faces** option in the **Overlay** section of the **Mesh Display** panel in the **Property** of the viewport.

[image]

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect, thank you! The only thing that now I miss is highlighting of selected faces =P